# CUDA: Sorting a vector< vector<int> > on the GPU

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, cuda, thrust

I have implemented my own comparator for STL's `sort` function, that helps sorting a `std::vector< std::vector<int> >` on the **CPU**. 
The user gives as an input a `std::vector< std::vector<int> >` and also a string variable like for example `021`. By having this string the sorting is done first on the first column, then on the third column and then on the second column. Example:

```
  1 2 3
  3 2 1
  1 1 1
  1 1 2
```

Let's say the string is `10`

The output will be

```
  1 1 1
  1 1 2
  1 2 3
  3 2 1
```

My CPU implementation uses a class called `Sorting`, this class is implemented with the following two files:

`Sorting.h`

```
class Sorting{

   private:

   public:

Sorting();
~Sorting();
std::vector<std::vector<int>> applySort(std::vector<std::vector<int>>
    data,const std::string& attr);

 };
```

`Sorting.cpp`

```
 Sorting::Sorting(){}

 Sorting::~Sorting(){}


 std::vector<std::vector<int>> Sorting::applySort(
      std::vector<std::vector<int>> data, const std::string& attr){

         std::sort(data.begin(), data.begin()+data.size(), Comparator(attr));

         return data;
  }
```

`Comparator.h`

```
   class Comparator{

   private:
     std::string attr;

   public:
     Comparator(const std::string& attr) { this->attr = attr; }

     bool operator()(const std::vector<int>& first, const std::vector<int>&
          second){

    size_t i;
    for(i=0;i<attr.size();i++){
        if(first[attr.at(i) - '0'] < second[attr.at(i) - '0']) return true;
        else if(first[attr.at(i) - '0'] > second[attr.at(i)-'0'])          
             return  false;
    }
    return false;
  }

  };
```

My implementation has been tested and it works properly. I'm interested in doing a similar CUDA implementation that would take advantage of GPU's capabilities in order to produce the output much more faster.

Initially I thought because my goal is a bit confusing, maybe changing an already known implementation for sorting in the GPU would do my job. However I started searching many implementations like the one described here: http://blogs.nvidia.com/2012/09/how-tesla-k20-speeds-up-quicksort-a-familiar-comp-sci-code/ and it made me realize that it would be something difficult to achieve.

I'm not sure if this is the best course of action. I started searching for libraries and found `Thrust`. However, although Thrust allows you to define your own comparator, in a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869049/cuda-thrust-library-how-can-i-create-a-host-vector-of-host-vectors-of-integers) I asked yesterday I learned that it's not possible to create a `host_vector < host_vector<int> >`.

And I guess transforming my vector of vectors to a single vector wouldn't help me that much because I have no idea how I would then have to implement my comparator class.

I would like to hear your opinion on this issue:

1. how should I approach this problem?
2. Is it possible to achieve it with `Thrust`?
3. Would doing it in the GPU give a much better performance on my overall code? Note that the vector of vectors can be huge, millions of rows but only a few(5-10) columns.
4. Would it be better to design my own sort or change a sort function that is already available? This although sounds like a good idea, in practice I feel like it would take me a lot of effort to achieve. Using a simple comparator and a sort function from a library would be the best for me, however the limitations of `Thrust` don't allow me to do so.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are the individual vectors to be sorted all the same length?

Comment: If you are referring to the total number of rows of different inputs, they are of different lengths.

If you are referring to the columns, for one input vector we have the same amount of columns for each row.

Comment: You basically cannot do this, because you cannot instantiate a `std::vector` or its equivalent on the GPU. As I said in your last question, you will be better served by using linear memory allocations of the underlying POD types for storage on the GPU.

Comment: wouldn't it be possible to somehow use the host_vector that the Thrust provides in order to do this job? My input to the function although is generated dynamically, can be changed in order to be simple 2d array. Would using a 2d array instead of a vector help in achieving my goal? I can't understand why it's not possible to allocate a 2d array in the gpu, since a 2d array can be modeled as a 1d array.

Comment: However If I decide to create a 1d array, then how would I create the Comparator? The operator() function would have to take a single integer of the array, so even if you know the width(ie amount of columns) you won't be able to do anything.

Comment: Note I said linear memory. You are free to store a multidimensional array in linear memory. If you are worried about how to store a "jagged" array where one dimension is not of constant length, use a scheme like an old school compressed sparse matrix format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see that you are trying to implement a lexicographical sorting technique(but i have did it with single 1D huge vector), well i have been there and i have implemented a function which sorts the vectors but actually it is lagging way behind the lexicographical sorting, anyways i am not sure if i can post the code here, so if you need any help i would be glad to help

PS: look into the implementation of lexicographical_sort.cu in thrust example code (i have tweaked it also but that one also is lagging behind)
The comparator function you might need in order to check from two distintive places in 1D vector (which contains all the data) is listed down (by the way, this technique is way slower then CPU) but who know you might come up with idea to improve it or use it better then i do

```
struct arbitrary_functor
{
    template <typename Tuple>   __host__ __device__
        void operator()(Tuple t)
        {
            if(thrust::get<0>(t)>thrust::get<1>(t))
                thrust::get<2>(t) = 1;
            else
                thrust::get<2>(t) = 0;
        }
};

int checkLexo_1vec(const thrust::device_vector<char> & A, int bv1, int bv2, int N){
    int i;

    thrust::device_vector<char> temp(N);
    thrust::device_vector<char> sum(N);

    thrust::for_each(thrust::make_zip_iterator(
                        thrust::make_tuple(A.begin()+bv2, A.begin()+bv1,temp.begin())),
                    thrust::make_zip_iterator(
                        thrust::make_tuple(A.end()+(bv2+N),A.end()+(bv1+N), temp.end())),
                    arbitrary_functor());


    thrust::inclusive_scan(temp.begin(),temp.end(),sum.begin());

    int a = thrust::lower_bound(sum.begin(),sum.end(),1) - sum.begin();

    thrust::for_each(thrust::make_zip_iterator(
                        thrust::make_tuple(A.begin()+bv1, A.begin()+bv2, temp.begin())),
                    thrust::make_zip_iterator(
                        thrust::make_tuple(A.end()+(bv1+N), A.end()+(bv2+N),temp.end())),
                    arbitrary_functor());

    thrust::inclusive_scan(temp.begin(),temp.end(),sum.begin());

    int b = thrust::lower_bound(sum.begin(),sum.end(),1) - sum.begin();

    if(a<=b)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want to do. However having a vector of vectors I need to lexicographically sort them so that in each row the vector "A" is always less than or equal to the vector "B", according to the ordering specified by the string.

Doing so sequentially worked very well for me, however a few days ago I saw that a good gpu sort can sort 100 million integers in less than 1 second while it takes a lot more in the CPU, so I thought maybe doing this kind of sort in the GPU would be the best option for me, however as I understand the limitations are too many in order to achieve this

Comment: note that the vector "A" must be before the vector "B" in the overall vector.

Comment: Well i have pasted snippet of code, if you need working too it is simple you just have to use it in this order
`int x = checkLexo1vec(vec_2_check_from,start_pose1, start_pose2,N);` where `N=elements in any one instance(in your case 3)`

Comment: No worries ksm001, i know there are problems in checking lexographically two vectors (and i think CPU is doing better because the code for sequential checking stops on the moment it finds the mismatch) but GPU dont know the value of last outcome so it goes along and do the work anyways :/ well if my checkLexo_1vec is hard to understand at some point feel free to contact

Comment: by the way, i have also did the `vector<vector ....>` thing, and it is even worse then sorting 1D vector, the reason behind the slow speed is because the swapping of data is required to change the value of on entire row of vector (if it is found that they are in wrong order) this task is way too slow (even for thrust, not to mention the slow checking of functions), so in my 1vec technique i am actually updating the pointers to the device_vector instead of swapping the whole data.....
But my second attempt is also very slow :/

Comment: Thank you for the information, I had imagined that this would be difficult to achieve, I will probably stick to the sequential version(at least for now), if it's so slow in just doing the sorting I guess it would become very slow if I had to sort like a million vectors due to the extra time it would take to send the data to the GPU and back...

Answer (score 0):

i have found a reasonable method which can finally beat the CPU (not in terms of time but in terms of data elements)
actually my new method involves using of thrust::mismatch and i am attaching code for the function

The good thing about this version is that running time of this function is 2ms approx. with very large amount of data such as `N = 1000000 to N = 1000`, anyways i am posting the function code and do let me know if you find any of user find some other improvements which can reduce the overall running time

```
template<typename Ivec>    
int lexoMM(Ivec vec, int bv1, int bv2, int N){

  typedef thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator Iterator;
  thrust::pair<Iterator,Iterator> result;

  result = thrust::mismatch(vec.begin()+bv1, vec.begin()+(bv1+N-1), vec.begin()+bv2);

if(result.first == vec.end()){
      //cout<<"Both are equal (right order)"<<endl;
      return 1;
  }
else if(result.first>result.second){
    //cout<<"Wrong order"<<endl;
    //cout<<*result.first<<","<<*result.second;
    return 0;
}
else{
    //cout<<"Right order"<<endl;
    //cout<<*result.first<<","<<*result.second;
    return 1;
    }
```

}

PS: i feel like i really wasted my time in order to implementing my own version of this same thing, but `thrust` is awsome :)

Comment: by the way, the advantage of this function might be utilized on large amount of data which is not in my case  (as my max data in any vector will be 4096 max) :(